# Refresh token refresh rate

Tags: jwt, token, refresh-token

Let's say we have a refresh token with a lifetime of a month. Within that month with each subsequent call to the "auth" endpoint(with username and password) should the same refresh token be returned, or should a new one be generated, and why?

Long story short...should the user be forced to log in again after the lifetime of the refresh token expires, or should he be allowed to refresh his tokens indefinitely?

Answer (score 1):

The usual pattern I have seen used is that the initial authentication or refresh call is what would return both a new access token *and* a new refresh token.  One use of the refresh token is for acquiring a new access token after the current/old access token has expired.  Here is an example workflow:

- user authenticates via 1FA/2FA to the server
- access and refresh tokens are returned; refresh token lives slightly longer than access token, by design
- after some time, the access token expires, and the user sends the refresh token to the server
- a new access and refresh token are returned, continue from the second step above

As the refresh token intentionally will outlive the access token, there is no need to send a new refresh token with each request.  Rather, simply let the user initiate the request for a new access/refresh token when the time comes.

Comment: Thx for laying the whole story, but my question still remains in dot number 4. I understand that the access token must be new, but should the refresh token be new if the previous one has not yet expired? And if so ... why?

Comment: I answered that question in the end of my answer.  No, just send a new refresh token with the new access token.

Comment: Which one is it? "As the refresh token intentionally will outlive the access token, there is no need to send a new refresh token with each request" or "just send a new refresh token "?

Comment: The patterns that I have seen used will piggy-back a new refresh token with a new access token.  You don't need to keep sending new refresh tokens with each request, that defeats the purpose IMHO.

Comment: Ok misunderstanding again. I understand there are 2 endpoints:
1) "auth" endpoint - where the user sends username and password and receives a pair of the access-token and refresh-token
2) "refresh" endpoint where one sends a pair of old access-token and active refresh-token and receives only new access-token.

I am interested in the "auth" endpoint, and its return. I understand the access-token part should always be a new one. 
The question is about the refresh-token part.
Should it always be a new one or only a new one if the old one has expired?

Comment: Well the auth endpoint should really only be hit 1) when the user first tries to access the application via 1FA/2FA, or 2) if the session lapses because the refresh token itself becomes stale or expires.  In both cases, a new refresh token should be returned.  The application doesn't know the status of the previous refresh token, but it doesn't have to, and can probably assume either option 1) or 2).

Comment: Doesn't that imply that a user would never have to give its credentials again provided it constantly refreshes its tokens, and do I want that?

Comment: ...that is one main purpose of the refresh token.  The refresh token allows the session to rollover under the hood, without the user being forced to reauthenticate, which might interrupt the user experience.  If you _don't_ want automatic session rollover, then just drop refresh tokens entirely, and force the user to reauthenticate after a certain time.

Comment: Thx for your answers and patience...